# PHP script - task result handling

Tags: php, exception, scheduled-tasks

I can not find information how to best practice addresses the following situation.

Cron run in defining interval script (see below). If everything is ok, will take place and everything is working. However, if an error occurs (in the code notes //VALIDATION ...) I don't know about errors (I must manually run the script in the browser and debug via var_dump, echo, browse all logs, etc.).

I would like to rich a state where I get the final report of the Cron job (eg http://www.vblog.ch/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/veeam-report.jpg) - basic data (summary result of job) + information where the error occurred or what was run correct (eg the file XXX has been processed, Unable to remove files, Directory XXX does not exist). Further, if an error occurs when a part of the program to continue further (see notes again in the script).

Thank you, Petr

```
#region <<< Process all files >>>

    // get all eported directories with files
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($myDOMDocumentConfiguration);
    $searchNodes = $xpath->query('//Configuration/Directory');

    // go throw all directories
    foreach( $searchNodes as $searchNode )
    {
        // VALIDATION
        // ERROR CAN BE HERE - DIRECTORY NOT EXISTS
        // TRY NEXT DIRECTORY

        // find all files in defined path (pathnames matching a pattern)
        foreach(glob($searchNode->getAttribute('FilePathD')) as $strFile)
        {
            // convert csv file to array
            $arrFiles = Record::ConvertCsv2Array($strFile);

            // VALIDATION
            // ERROR CAN BE HERE - CANNOCT CONVERT CSV FILE TO ARRAY
            // TRY NEXT FILE

            // go throw all items
            foreach($arrFiles as $FileItem)
            {
                // prepare SQL query and insert ot to database
                $strSqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO ....';

                // VALIDATION
                // ERROR CAN BE HERE - BAD INSERT TO DATABASE
                // IGNORE, APPEND ONLY INFORMATION TO LOG
            }

            // if file is inserted to database, delete it
            unlink($FileItem);

            // VALIDATION
            // ERROR CAN BE HERE - CAN NOT DELETE FILE
            // IGNORE, APPEND ONLY INFORMATION TO LOG
        }

        // VALIDATION
        // ERROR CAN BE HERE - DIRECTORY NOT EXISTS
        // TRY NEXT DIRECTORY

        // delete all analytics files in defined path (pathnames matching a pattern)
        foreach(glob($searchNode->getAttribute('FilePathA')) as $strFile)
        {
            // cmr files are onyl analytics - delete it
            unlink($strFile);

            // VALIDATION
            // ERROR CAN BE HERE - CAN NOT DELETE FILE
            // IGNORE, APPEND ONLY INFORMATION TO LOG
        }
    }

#endregion

echo '=== Task has been completed ===';
```

Comment: The usual approach for this is pretty easy: just write a log file for the cron job and log every important detail into it. No even when your script crashes you have all the output exactly up to that point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree that logging is the basic, but if problems occur during script processing (eg. directory not exist, eventually script go throw exceptions, it'ss not a reason to terminate the script. Specifically - after read the values ​​from the csv file, I try to connect to the IP address on port 161 and read some values ​​- the script may give an error (throw excception) on Timeout, Connection refused etc. This is a "little things" to kill all script. Therefore if I understand  - log and manage program logic I must manage by several nested try-catch blocks. Is that correct?

Comment: I never claimed you have to terminate a script yourself. Nothing against handling errors, be it by testing for conditions or by catching exceptions. This is something I take for granted, one should _always_ implement as robust as possible, so error tolerant. The problem usually is unexpected issues your script does not handle where it gets terminated by the interpreter. in such cases logging is the best approach to find what actions ran successfully and where the problem blocked further actions.